# Upload multiple files to SQL Server without access to the Server Box

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssis, bulk-insert

I am trying to create a process that would bulk upload multiple csv files periodically to individual tables in SQL server. The issue I am having is those files are not located on the same server.

I can use the bulk upload command to upload files from a folder on the SQL server box but not from our shared drive which is located on a different server. There are multiple people who would be running this process and so it might not be feasible because not all of them would get that kind of access to the SQL server box.

Is there any way of accomplishing this with the same level of efficiency and speed?
I have thought of sending each line in the csv files but those files are huge and would take a long time
Just looking for ideas to make this work.
Would SSIS be less or more or equally efficient?

Comment: It's not clear to me, after reading this a couple of times, exactly what you need.  Do you need the users to be able to move or copy the files to the SQL Server?  Do you need an automated process to move or copy the files?  Can the files be moved or copied on a scheduled basis, or must that only occur on user demand?  Is there a requirement for this to be 100% seamless to the user (i.e., users don't have to specify what file to copy or move)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no transformations involved, you could write this process fairly simply in SSIS with a for loop in the control flow that iterates over a file directory, then passes each file name as a variable to a data flow.  The filename for the csv would be bound to that variable, and your destination could similarly be bound to the file name.  Just use bulk mode in your target component and you should get pretty good efficiency.  This works great if the folder is accessible to all users and you add a step to either check and see that files in the directory are processed or move them somewhere else when they've been processed.  The SSIS process could be invoked from the SSIS catalog on the SQL Server directly, or scheduled on a regular basis.

Alternatively, you could use the [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) for a CLI experience.  This is probably a lot simpler in that it doesn't require writing an SSIS process and management of that process, but it requires more knowledge on the end of the user invoking it.  This tool doesn't require the files be on the server: you provide a path to the file as the invoking user, along with credentials to authenticate, and the tool will handle the data movement.

Comment: This was informative enough to be considered an answer. I know there are other ways as well but the ones mentioned were better in my scenario. Especially the bcp utility.